# Biblatex - Combine Papers using citet

Tags: biblatex, biber

I cite elements from my bibfile using `\citet{key}`. The reference appears as "Name1, and Name2 (year)" in text where year is a link leading to the bibliography. Now, I want to cite two papers from the same authors from different years. Instead of

> Model XYZ is analyzed by Name1, and Name2 (2019) and Name1, and Name2 (2020).

I'd prefer to have something like

> Model XYZ is analyzed by Name1, and Name2 (2019, 2020).

Of course, now 2019 should be a link to the 2019 paper in the bibliography and 2020 a link to the 2020 paper in the bibliography. Any ideas of I could adjust the `\citet` command?

---

I use `biblatex` as follows.

```
\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear, 
            sorting=nyt,
            backend=biber, 
            natbib=true,             
            uniquename = false, 
            uniquelist = false,
            firstinits=false, 
            hyperref=true,
            dashed=false,
            backref=false, 
            maxbibnames=99, 
            maxcitenames=3,
            isbn=false, 
            doi=false]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Not immediately relevant for you question, but with `style=ext-authoryear,` (and also with `style=ext-authoryear-comp,`) `sorting=nyt,` is already the default, so there is no need to give the option again. The option `firstinits=false,` was renamed to `giveninits=false,` a while ago, it is recommended to use the new name. For (almost?) all intents and purposes the option `hyperref=true,` is no better than the default `hyperref=auto,`, the only difference is a warning if you don't load the `hyperref` package. I suggest you drop the `hyperref=true,`.

Comment: @moewe Thank you very much for the hints. I incorporated all of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a `-comp` version of the style you are currently using. `-comp` styles compress multiple citation labels by the same authors to avoid duplication of names.

Luckily both the standard styles and `biblatex-ext` offer a `-comp` version of the author-year style.

Replace

```
style=ext-authoryear,
```

with

```
style=ext-authoryear-comp,
```

For example

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=ext-authoryear-comp, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\textcite{knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b}
\end{document}
```

[image: Knuth (1984, 1986)]

Comment: I can't upvote your answer (lack of reputation) but you'd deserve 10 upvotes. It works perfectly. Thank you so much!