# How to cite author(year1,year2) in latex with authoryear style?

Tags: biblatex

I use the following package:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=author year,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534366/35864 help? You need `style=authoryear-comp`.

Comment: Off-topic, but you may want to look into switching from `backend=bibtex,` to `backend=biber,`. Normally that should be as easy as changing the option value from `bibtex` to `biber` and running Biber instead of BibTeX (or telling your editor to do that for you, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864).

Comment: Which code did you try? What error did you get?

Comment: I use the following codes:% Literaturverzeichnis mit BibLKaTeX
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\bibliography{bibliography}

Comment: And what is the error? (Note that `sorting=sty,` may not be the best in combination `style=authoryear-comp,` since your readers will probably expect the author-year bibliography to be sorted by name-year-title and not name-title-year.)

Comment: I want my citation is shown as : merton (1969,1971). However when I use the code as you advised :  \usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-comp,natbib=true,sorting=nty]{biblatex} and the code in text as  \textcite{merton1969optimum, merton1971lifetime}, then the result is as follow: merton1969lifetime;merton1971lifetime

Comment: Did you run LaTeX, Biber, LaTeX, LaTeX on your document (where LaTeX is your favourite flavour of LaTeX: pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, ...). See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864. Since you switched to `backend=biber,` you need to run Biber and not BibTeX.

Comment: I run pdfLaTeX+MakeIndex+BibTeX since I need pdf result, however when running Biber there is no pdf output at all

Comment: Biber alone does not generate a PDF. You need to run pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX.

Comment: could you possibly advise me how can I upgrade my editor to have pdfLaTeX, Biber, pdfLaTeX, pdfLaTeX. since currently I have only Biber in my editor to choose?

Comment: Can't you select pdfLaTeX? What editor do you use? Can you post a screenshot of the compilation options?

Comment: fortunately it works, thanks a lot